# Initializing a variable as undefined

Tags: javascript

Doing some refactoring, I noticed an unusual pattern I'm not familiar with. Properties and variables that do not yet have a value are initiated with `undefined` declared explicitly, despite the fact that value-less variables and object properties would evaluate to `undefined` anyways:

```
var foo = undefined;
this.prop = undefined;
```

**Is there a reason to do this?**

Comment: Some people like to be really explicit, that's all.

Comment: Questions:  doesn't `"use strict";` turn undefined variable use into an error?  Are you familiar with hoisting?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `var foo = undefined;` will hide any versions of `foo` declared in an outer scope.

Comment: @StevenBurnap right- wouldn't `var foo;` do the same thing though?

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  One advantage might be by explicitly setting to undefined,you're sending the message that you didn't forget to set it to some value.

Comment: In "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers", the author writes that you should never explicitly initialize to undefined.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Right- and in that case my question is why not use `null`? `null` is explicit AND doesn't carry the same confusion that `undefined` does. `undefined` is the result of trying to access a nonexistant object member, so a programmer trying to debug would see that `this.prop` is `undefined`, and might think that that property is nonexistant. Were `this.prop` `null` however, the developer would see that the object member existed.

Comment: @MattFenwick does `"use strict"` turn undefined variable use into an error? This project is not in strict mode- should it be? I am indeed familiar with hoisting and know that variable definitions are hoisted to the top of their scope and initialized as `undefined`- but is there any reason a human would write that?

Comment: @stinkycheeseman the decision about strict mode is up to you; I always use it because it tells me when I do stupid things, but that's just a personal choice.  Re hoisting: the fact that Javascript hoists variables is, for some people, a valid reason why a human should write the same way -- because then the code is being more "honest" about what it's doing.  I first heard of this idea from Douglas Crockford and his JSLint tool.  One last thing: my comments don't apply to your second example, sorry.

Comment: what happen if someone wrote `undefined = 1` somewhere and get executed?

Comment: @BryanChen That's what this idiom was for in libraries:  `(function(undefined) { ...your library here... })()` - note nothing is passed in.  That resets `undefined` to a real undefined inside the scope of the immediately-called function.  Nowadays it's not needed, as modern browsers silently don't allow changing its value - `undefined` is always `undefined`.

Comment: In javascript there is a difference between a missing property and a property that exists, but has the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible the author came from an environment where all variables were required to be initialized when declared. Some code-checking tools will also complain if variables are not initialized before they are used (even if the first use is to assign a value).

Comment: are there any merits to doing this in javascript?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Whenever I've seen this, it was always done because it was required by a coding standard.

Comment: Functionally, absolutely not. But for code readability/maintenance? Very likely so. The one advantage it gives is that you are now aware that `this.prop` is an intentional member of `this` (whatever this is), and it will likely get set in another method, and it is more obvious that `prop` can be read and written. Other ways to do this? `this.prop = null`, or maybe inline documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Given your two examples, I always do the second one, but never the first.

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = undefined;
    ....
}
```

This creates an explicit list of properties available at a glance for maintenance purposes.<sup>1</sup>  It's equivalent to declaring public members in class-based object oriented languages:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = null;
```

Relying on the default `undefined` in Javascript is similar to using `setattr` to create dynamic properties in Python - you can do it, and it's the right solution in some rare cases, but it's not going to help the maintainers.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I don't use `null` for this, because sometimes `null` is a valid value - checking if a property is `null` or `undefined` tells me if it got initialized at all before being used somewhere.</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by `null` is a valid value? I can think of an example where checking for `undefined` isn't clear: imagine if you set `this.foo` and `this.bar` to `undefined`. If I, a new developer to your project, try to evaluate `this.baz`, it will return `undefined` just like `this.bar` and `this.foo`. I have no way of distinguishing between what properties have been *initialized* and which ones simply don't exist.

Comment: @stinkycheeseman The point of using `undefined` isn't to initialize them, it's to "declare" them without initializing them, which helps for maintenance - having a list of which properties are valid.  `null` can't be used effectively for that because sometimes the property is known to not exist - for example `user.middle_name` would be `null` for a person that just plain doesn't have one.